# How to deal with SNMP IfinOctets / ifoutOctets Collectd / ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, snmp, kibana-4, collectd

I'm having some problems with aggregated data polled by Collectd and stored in ElasticSearch ( v2.1.1 ) using Logstash. We want to simple visualize SNMP current bandwidth data in Kibana 4. This is working fine, but we are getting the total amount of bandwidth in tx / rx what ever is transmitted/received per interface.
( type_instance: IF-MIB::IfDescr values: IfinOctets, IfOutOctets)

I'm thinking about 2 possible options to correct this values:

- Editting the collectd configuration file with a possible script and doing some math??
- Or is there a method / function query in kibana 4 that is able to fix this? For example: Compare both values tx / rx from the newest timestamp with the timestamp before, and doing some range query?

Please could somebody help me out here?